# How to pass multiple thread as argument in Kafka ProducerPerformance tool?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I wanted to pass number of threads that will send message to Kafka broker as a argument to ProducerPerformance tool.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot, you have to increase or decrease the throughput based on your tests. 
Kafka performance tool will take of this internally.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source code, it seems to be single threaded.

You can run multiple of the tool at once like this, though

```
nohup kafka-run-class ... > run1.txt 2&>1 &
nohup kafka-run-class ... > run2.txt 2&>1 &
```

Comment: Can we have something like passing number of threads as a parameter which will create the those many number of threads internally to produce messages?

Comment: There is no such parameter. The code is on Github, if you want to look at it

Comment: https://github.com/becketqin/kafka/blob/KAFKA-3554/tools/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/tools/ProducerPerformance.java

Here we can see there is a parameter to pass number of threads.

Comment: That's a fork. Not the official project https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/tools/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/tools/ProducerPerformance.java